# Regular expression to extract number before/after word

Tags: regex, stata

I have `10000` descriptions and I want to use regular expressions to extract the number associated with the phrase ``arrested''.

For example:

```
"police arrests 4 people"
"7 people were arrested".
```

The numbers range from `1-99`.

I have tried the following code:

```
gen arrest= regexm(description, "(^[1-9][0-9]$)[ ]*(arrests|arrested)")
```

I cannot simply extract just the number, because the descriptions also mention numbers that have nothing to do with arrests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:([1-9]?[0-9])[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}(?:arrests|arrested))|(?:(?:arrests|arrested)[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}([1-9]?[0-9]))
```

It divides the search into 2 by alternation, whether the number is before or after 'arrests|arrested'.

It creates a non capturing `Group`, that matches a `number` from 1-9 (which is optional) and a number from 0-9. This is followed by matching `0 - 20 of any letter` and Space (the other Words) before it matches '`arrests OR arrested.` It then ORs that with the opposite situation (where the number comes last).

This will match, if the number is `within 20 chars` from '`arrests|arrested`'.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
(\d+)[^,.\d\n]+?(?=arrest|custody)|(?<=arrest|custody)[^,.\d\n]+?(\d+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kpoO0a/3)

Keep in mind, this will not match textual versions of the number (i.e., five people were arrested) - so you would have to incorporate that if desired.

---

## Breaking down the pattern

- `(\d+)[^,.\d\n]+?(?=arrest|custody)` First option if # comes before watched terms

  - `(\d+)` the number to capture, with `+` one or more digits
  - `[^,.\d\n]+?` matches anything except a comma `,`, period `.`, digit `\d`, or new line `\n`. These prevent FPs from different sentences (must be contained in the same sentence) - `+?` one or more times (lazy)
  - `(?=arrest|custody)` positive look ahead checking for either word:
- `(?<=arrest|custody)[^,.\d\n]+?(\d+)` Second option if # comes after watched terms

  - `(?<=arrest|custody)` positive lookbehind checking that the word comes before #
  - `[^,.\d\n]+?` matches anything except a comma `,`, period `.`, digit `\d`, or new line `\n`. These prevent FPs from different sentences (must be contained in the same sentence) - `+?` one or more times (lazy)
  - `(\d+)` the number to capture, with `+` one or more digits

### Miscellaneous Notes

If you want to add textual representations of your numbers, then you would incorporate that into the `(\d+)` capturing group.

If you have any additional terms to watch for other than **arrested** or **custody**, you would add those terms to both lookaround groups

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me (solution based on @PoulBak's idea):

```
clear

input strL var1
"This is 1 long string saying that police arrests 4 people"
"3 news outlets today reported that 7 people were arrested"
"several witnesses saw 5 people arrested and other 3 killed"
end

generate var2 = ustrregexs(0) if ustrregexm(var1, "(?:([1-9]?[0-9])[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}(?:arrests|arrested))|(?:(?:arrests|arrested)[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}([1-9]?[0-9]))")

list

   +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                       var1                     var2 |
   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1. |  This is 1 long string saying that police arrests 4 people                arrests 4 |
2. |  3 news outlets today reported that 7 people were arrested   7 people were arrested |
3. | several witnesses saw 5 people arrested and other 3 killed        5 people arrested |
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```